# Redux. Is .map() makes reducer non-pure function?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I just want to understand is the usage of `.map()` inside `reducers` makes them non-pure? I clearly understand that pure functions is the functions that always return predictable (lets say dirty - "the same") result. But I think that usage of `.map()` inside `reducer` makes result non-predictable, because it lets him go ahead by one of two ways in ternary operation, that is a non-puse function way. So, just look on my reducer code and say is I'm wrong or not?

Thank you! )

```
  // .. reducer
  [SELECT_CDS]: (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    crimesByType: state.crim.map(
      (cri, i) =>
        i === 0
          ? {
              ...cri,
              additionalInfo: {
                ...cri.addition,
                CDsLeft: true
              }
            }
          : crime
    )
  })
```

Comment: `map` has nothing to do with it. "Unpredictable"? How is it unpredictable? Will it return the same output, every time, for the same input?

Comment: @DaveNewton thank you for your comment, but it make me stumb, istead of help with my question.

Comment: Your code is pure. It produces the same output given the same input.

Comment: It *answers* your question by making you answer a question: will your reducer always return the same result for the same input? How could it *not* return the same result for the same input? Whether or not it uses `map` is immaterial: *how* a function creates its result is not the issue--whether or not it always returns the same result for the same input is.

Answer (score 2):

A reducer should be pure function, meaning that if the reducer is called twice with the same input, the output should also be the same.

In your case, the reducer is pure, because even though your `map()` and ternary operator give different results for different elements of the array, the final result will always be the same if the original array and action are the same.